# Cannot make POST request with JSON from react/axios to restify server

Tags: json, reactjs, cors, axios, restify

I have a restify set up like this:

```
var restify = require('restify');

const server = restify.createServer();

//server.use(restify.plugins.acceptParser(server.acceptable)); // [1]
server.use(restify.plugins.queryParser());
server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser());

server.use(function(req, res, next) {
  console.log(req); // <-- Never see the POST from React here
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
  next();
});
```

I define a bunch `GET` and `POST` routes and so far it worked perfectly fine. I called the server from an Android application, Python scripts and for testing simply using `curl`. No issues at all. Neat!

However, now I've implemented a Web application with React and want to make a request to the restify API using the `axios` package. `GET` requests are fine, so I exclude any typos in the URL or such things.

But a POST request like the following won't work:

```
var data = {"test": "hello"};
axios.post("http://.../api/v1/message/question/public/add", data)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log("Test question sent!");
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

When I check with the browser developer tools, I can see that the browser is trying to make an `OPTIONS` request (not a `POST`) to that URL. I assume, from what I've read, that is because the browser is making a "preflighted request". The problem is that I get an `405 Method Not Allowed` error:

```
Request URL: http://.../api/v1/message/question/public/add
Request method: OPTIONS
Remote address: ...
Status code: 405 Method Not Allowed

Response headers (178 B)    
  Server: restify
  Allow: POST
  Content-Type: application/json
  Content-Length: 62
  Date: Sat, 09 Sep 2017 08:16:32 GMT
  Connection: keep-alive
Request headers (485 B) 
  Host: ...
  User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linu…) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0
  Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xm…plication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
  Accept-Language: en-ZA,en-GB;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
  Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
  Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
  Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
  Origin: http://...
  DNT: 1
  Connection: keep-alive
```

But why? I allow all `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` in restify. Everything works, except from `POST` requests and only when they come from the browser (with the React Web app). I think it's because of the `OPTIONS` request, but I have no idea how to handle it.

By the way with `JSON.stringify(data)`, the `POST` requests gets through, but the API expects Json and not a string. And since with all other means it works perfectly fine, I don't want to change the restify code just to accommodate this issue.

[1] If I use this line, I get the following error: `AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: acceptable ([string]) is required at Object.acceptParser (/home/bob/node_modules/restify/lib/plugins/accept.js:30:12)`

Answer (score 3):

After a couple of more hours, I finally found a [solution](https://github.com/TabDigital/restify-cors-middleware). I've changed my `restify` server code as follows:

```
var restify = require("restify");
var corsMiddleware = require('restify-cors-middleware')

var cors = corsMiddleware({
  preflightMaxAge: 5, //Optional
  origins: ['*'],
  allowHeaders: ['API-Token'],
  exposeHeaders: ['API-Token-Expiry']
});


// WITHOUT HTTPS
const server = restify.createServer();

server.pre(cors.preflight);
server.use(cors.actual);
...
(rest is the same as above)
```

To be honest, I've no real idea what it actual does. But it's working and it the cost me too much energy for today already. I hope it will help others at some point. Everything seems to be rather recent changes from `restify`.

Answer (score 1):

If your server isn’t allowing `OPTIONS` by default, you can add an explicit handler:

```
server.opts(/\.*/, function (req, res, next) {
    res.send(200);
    next();
});
```

Another possible problem is that you won’t have the effect intended the following headers:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
```

The `*` wildcard values there are allowed by the spec, but browsers don’t yet support them. So what you must do instead is, explicitly specify in those values the methods and headers to allow:

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'content-type');
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST');
```

That’s because the request headers shown for the CORS preflight `OPTIONS` request have this:

```
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Origin: http://...
```

And what those request headers indicate is, the browser’s asking the server, *Some code running at this origin wants to make a `POST` request to your server that adds a specific `Content-Type` to the request. Are you OK with receiving `POST` requests that add their own `Content-Type`?*

So in response to that preflight `OPTIONS` request, the browser expects to receive an `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` response header which explicitly allows `POST`, along with an `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header which explicitly allows `Content-Type`.

Comment: I found a solution, please see my answer. I've actually tried explicit settings instead of wildcards, but nothing worked. Whether there was an `OPTIONS` in `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` or not didn't make any difference. I've quickly tried your solution. The `OPTIONS` request does return a 200 now, but there's not `POST` following up. Again, independent if I use wildcards or not. I guess I'm still missing somehing.

Comment: Your reply certainly went into the right direction, and I find your Layman explanation at the end very useful -- it's far from my background. Hence my upvote. Much appreciated!